# How to read information from file to a matrix?

Tags: c++, file, matrix

I tried to do this, but this didnt work...

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std; 

void afisare(int place[9][9]){
    for(int i = 0; i<9;i++){
        for(int j =1; j<9;j++){
            cout << place[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    int place[9][9],n,j = 0; 
    string s;

    fin.open("file.in");
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                fin >> place[i][j];
            }
        } 
    fin.close();

    afisare(place);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and this show me that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tESK.png)
when this need to show that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zSqs.png)
help me please. :*|

Comment: Please show us the *full* program as text well as the input file as text so we can try your code for ourselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: You should check if fin was successfully opened before reading from it. `if (!fin) { cerr << strerror(errno) << endl; return 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that your program was not successful in opening the file.

1. Add a check to verify that opening the file was successful.
2. Add a check when reading the contents of the file. If there is an error, add code to deal with it.

```
fin.open("file.in");
if ( !fin )
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open file.\n";
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      if ( !(fin >> place[i][j]) ) {
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to read number from file.\n";
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }
}
```

If you see any of those error messages,

1. Try running the program from the directory where file.in is located, or
2. Use absolute path of the file.

Comment: its rlly coz of that but both file are in 1 folder and however this dont work, but if i work sith stirng this work perfectly.